# Sync a shared SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sync, external-users

Is it possible for an external user to be able to sync a shared SharePoint site to their computer?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available at this point, here is MSFT person reply on [similar question:](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onedrivefb-mso_win10-mso_o365b/syncing-external-sharepoint-site/5a23b3c0-2ce8-44b5-a063-1da5beeee6d5)

> I would like to explain that we can see those files in and outside our
>   organizations which we have permissions with browser. We can sync
>   files in our tenant (OneDrive for Business library or SharePoint
>   Online team site library) with OneDrive sync client. However, we
>   cannot sync files outside of our organizations as external user with
>   OneDrive sync client.

They recommend to register your concern on uservoice forum to get feedback from product group.

i have seen already a post is published there: [Enable sync for external users](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/13249206-enable-sync-for-external-users)

If you read it, it explain why it is blocked.

> "As a security measure, whenever you try to perform a sync, the
>   OneDrive for Business first accesses the subscription in order to
>   verify whether you are a licensed user and whether you have
>   permissions to access the required document library. Since an external
>   email address does not have a license assigned by your Office365
>   subscription, hence the first check by OneDrive for Business fails
>   thereby disallowing the sync to continue